# Replace every occurence of [b: "text"] to <b>text</b> where text can be anything

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace every occurence of `[b: "text"]` to `<b>text</b>` using JavaScript and RegEx. Currently I know how to replace `[b: ""]` to `<b></b>` using `'/\[b: ""\]/g'` but I can't figure out what to do if there is text between `"` symbols (it must be placed between html tags).

Comment: @DanielA.White I've been searching trough RegEx references for solution and tried a lot of different combinations but I just don't get it. Now i will study Arun answer about how it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [a capturing group (`(.*)`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_parentheses) to match the text between the quotes and use that in your replacement.

Note that if you have to handle escaped quotes inside the string or anything complex, you'll want to use a real parser rather than complicating the regex more (I'd suggest a tool like [PegJS](http://pegjs.org/)).

```js
var text = [
  '[b: ""]',
  '[b: "hello world"]',
  '[b:"hello terse"]'
];

var rex = /\[b:\s?"(.*)"\]/;
var out = text.map(function(line) {
  return line.replace(rex, '<b>$1</b>');
});

document.getElementById('r').textContent = JSON.stringify(out);
```

```html
<pre id=r></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var string = "";
var replaced = string.replace(/\[b:\s"(.*?)"\]/g, '<b>$1</b>')
```

Demo: [Example](http://regexr.com/3b6mf)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will capture empty and all characters between the quotes.

`text.match(/\[b: "(.+|)"]/g);`

Demo:http://www.regexr.com/3b6mi

`.+` captures one or more non-whitespace characters

`|` is an logical `OR`

`( )` creates a new capture group